# What is Not If and what does it have to do with strings

Tags: python

I have been reading about how to figure out if a string is empty or has value within Python and discovered Not If i done some reading and found out that Not will return true if a condition does not equal what the programmer expects it to this is used in a if statement like this if not how does this work with strings?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
Data = ""
if not Data:
    print 'Hello'
else:
    print 'Goodbye'
```

I expect the output to be Hello and wish to know how this works

Comment: Objects in python have a notion of truthy-ness or falsey-ness. You can always check this by casting a given object to a `bool`: `bool([])`, `bool("")`, `bool(None)`, `bool(-1)`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Truthy and Falsy? How is it different from True and False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Comment: In Python, the empty string, `''` , is considered *"falsey"*. All other strings are *"truthy"*. This is why `"Hello"` is printed

Answer (score 1):

`not object` is essentially a shorthand for `bool(object) == False`. It's generally used to negate the *truth value* of `object`.

However, the truth value of `object` depends on `object`'s type:

- If `object` is a boolean, then `True` evaluates to `True` and `False` evaluates to `False`.
- If `object` is an number (integer or floating-point), then `0` evaluates to `False` and any other value evaluates to `True`
- If `object` is a string, then the empty string `""` evaluates to `False` and any other value evaluates to `True` (this is your case at the moment)
- If `object` is a collection (e.g. list or dict), then an empty collection (`[]` or `{}`) evaluates to `False`, and any other value evaluates to `True`.
- If `object` is `None`, it evaluates to `False`. Barring the above cases, if `object` is not `None`, it will usually evaluate to `True`.

These are generally grouped into two categories of *truthy* and *falsey* values - a truthy value is anything that evaluates to `True`, whereas a falsey value is anything that evaluates to `False`.

Python programmers use `if not object:` as a shorthand to cover multiple of these at once. In general, if you're not sure, you should check more specifically. In your case:

```
data = ""
if data == "":
    print("Hello")
else:
    print("Goodbye")
```

or if you wanted to make sure that, say, `data` didn't end with the character `p`, you could do this:

```
data = "orange"
if not data.endswith(p):
    print("data does not end with p")
else:
    print("data ends with p")
```